# Multiple UITablewViewCell in UITableView's row

Tags: ios5, uitableview

is it possible to have multiple UITableViewCell(s) on a single row in UITableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. Simple as that.
`UITableView` is rather a list than a table.